# Firebase Database workouts issues

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created the Database in firebase and used for my hybrid application, Let you explain the application scenarios below.

I have a hybrid application in this app, We need to insert, update, delete, kind of operations using firebase.

As of now, I did the insert method kind of queries alone using code. So the thing is I want to create multiple tables in firebase is it possible ?

Because For example, I've userTable, adminTable and guestTable, So If I need to insert one userData before that I need to check already the user found or not in Admin table this kind of scenarios How can I do in firebase ?

How can I maintain multiple tables in the firebase Database dashboard?

I have the table name called "Inmate_Data" now I want to add one more Table called "Admin_Data" and How can I do a joint operation like connecting two table using Firebase.

And, I tried to add one more table using Import JSON option But while I inserting new JSON the old Table got deleted like the "Inmate_Data" deleted and new JSON got added.

Please guide me in this.

@FrankvanPuffelen - Please find the below coding part.

Actually, I created the form and saving the data into firebase using below code.

```
$scope.addInmateDataToFirebase = function() {

  alert('Firebase')

  var newPostKey = null;

  // Get a key for a new Post.
  newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('Tables/Inmate_Data').push().key;
  alert(newPostKey);

  var dateofjoin= $filter('date')($scope.IMDOJ, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
  var dateofbirth= $filter('date')($scope.IMDOB, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 

  console.log("Result"+ newPostKey);
  var admissionId="KAS"+pad(newPostKey,5);
  console.log("Padded number"+ pad(newPostKey,5));
  alert(admissionId);

            // A post entry.
            var postInmateData = {

              Inmate_ID: admissionId,
              Inmate_Name: $scope.IMfirstnameText,
              Inmate_Perm_Address1: $scope.IMAddress1 ,
              Inmate_Perm_Address2: $scope.IMAddress2 ,
              Inmate_Perm_City: $scope.IMCity,
              Inmate_Perm_State: $scope.IMState,
              Inmate_Perm_Pincode: $scope.IMPincode,
              Inmate_ProfilePhotoPath: $scope.IMProfilePhotoPath,
              Inmate_Temp_Address1: $scope.IMLocAddress1,
              Inmate_Temp_Address2: $scope.IMLocalAddress2,
              Inmate_Temp_City:$scope.IMGcity, 
              Inmate_Temp_State: $scope.IMGstate,
              Inmate_Temp_Pincode: $scope.IMGpincode,
              Inmate_Mobile: $scope.IMMobile,
              Inmate_DOB: dateofbirth,
              Inmate_EmpOrStudent: $scope.IMEmpStudent,
              Inmate_DOJ: dateofjoin,
              Inmate_ID_Type: $scope.IMIdcardType,
              Inmate_ID_No: $scope.IMIdcardno,
              Inmate_ProffPhotoPath: $scope.IMProofPhotoPath,
              Inmate_Status:$scope.IMStatus 


            };

            // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the list.
            var updates = {};
            updates['/Tables/Inmate_Data/' + newPostKey] = postInmateData;

            return firebase.database().ref().update(updates).then(function() {

              //$scope.ClearInMateDetails();

              alert(admissionId);
              $scope.statusMessage =  "Welcome to Kasthuri Hostel. Your Admission ID  is" + admissionId +" . Enjoy your Stay.";
              //sendSMS('9488627377',$scope.statusMessage);
              alert('Inmate data stored in cloud!');

              $scope.ClearInMateDetails();


            }, function(error) {

              alert (error);

            });

          }
```

Now the Inmate_data got stored. and I need to save the Inmate_alloc_data into firebase but before that, I need to check whether the Inmate_Id available in the Inmate_Data table in firebase.

Please find the below snap :

[image: Dashboard of firebase]

My suggestions :

For example like above screenshot now I've multiple tables like "Inmate_Data", "Inmate_Alloc", and more Shall I get all the data and store it in a local SQLite Db like same as "Inmate_Alloc_tbl" and "Inmate_Data_tbl" and finally If I update any values finally I want to get all values in the local database and store it in the firebase. Is it possible to handle ?

If so I can manage lots of SQL queries, right ? Because via firebase we can't able to manage all queries right ?
Please suggest your ideas.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. Also show the code of what you've already tried.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen pls check my updated question.